# faster way of reading word2vec txt in python

Tags: text, binary, word2vec

I have a standard word2vec output which is a .txt file formatted as follows:

```
[number of words] [dimension (300)]
word1 [300 float numbers separated by spaces]
word2 ...
```

Now I want to read at most `M` word representations out of this file. A simple way is to loop the first `M+1` lines in the file, and store the `M` vectors into a numpy array. But this is super slow, is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean, "is super slow"? Compared to what?

Because it's a given text format, there's no way around reading the file line-by-line, parsing the floats, and assigning them into a usable structure. But you might be doing things very inefficiently – without seeing your code, it's hard to tell.

The `gensim` library in Python includes classes for working with word-vectors in this format. And, its routines include an optional `limit` argument for reading just a certain number of vectors from the front of a file. For example, this will read the 1st 1000 from a file named `vectors.txt`:

```
word_vecs = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('word-vectors.txt', 
                                              binary=False,
                                              limit=1000)
```

I've never noticed it as being a particularly slow operation, even when loading something like the 3GB+ set of word-vectors Google released. (If it does seem super-slow, it could be you have insufficient RAM, and the attempted load is relying on virtual memory paging – which you never want to happe with a random-access data structure like this.)

If you then save the vectors in `gensim`'s native format, via `.save()`, and if the constituent numpy arrays are large enough to be saved as separate files, then you'd have the option of using `gensim`'s native `.load()` with the optional `mmap='r'` argument. This would entirely skip any parsing of the raw on-disk numpy arrays, just memory-mapping them into addressable space – making `.load()` complete very quickly. Then, as ranges of the array are accessed, they'd be paged into RAM. You'd still be paying the cost of reading-from-disk all the data – but incrementally, as needed, rather than in a big batch up front.

For example...

```
word_vecs.save('word-vectors.gensim')
```

...then later...

```
word_vecs2 = KeyedVectors.load('word_vectors.gensim', mmap='r')
```

(There's no 'limit' option for the native `.load()`.)